# Spring JPA Relationship column not showing in table

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpa

I am trying to create a relationship and whatever I do it will ever create a join table or just doesn't appear in the table. What am I doing wrong?
Here is all the different code I have tried and what it did

**Option 1**

SeasonTeams class

```
@Entity
public class Season_teams {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int seasont_id;
@OneToMany()
private List<Team> teams;
```

Teams class

```
@Entity
public class Team {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int Team_Id;
private String teamName;
private Blob Logo;
private String stadium;
@OneToOne
private TotalTeamStats tts;
@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(name="teams")
private Season_teams st;
```

This creates a 3rd table

**Option 2**

```
@Entity
public class Season_teams {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int seasont_id;
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="st")
private List<Team> teams;

@Entity
public class Team {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int Team_Id;
private String teamName;
private Blob Logo;
private String stadium;
@OneToOne
private TotalTeamStats tts;
@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(name="teams")
private Season_teams st;
```

This doesn't create a 3rd table but however doesn't create a column in the table for some reason!

**3rd Option**

```
@Entity
public class Season_teams {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int seasont_id;
@OneToMany()
@JoinColumn(name="st")
private List<Team> teams;

@Entity
public class Team {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int Team_Id;
private String teamName;
private Blob Logo;
private String stadium;
@OneToOne
private TotalTeamStats tts;
@ManyToOne
private Season_teams st;
```

This doesn't create a 3rd table but however doesn't create a column in the table for some reason!

What is wrong with my code, I have used code that I used to create other relationships and that either doesn't create a column or creates a join table. Any help would be greatly appreciative as I need this for my 3rd year project at uni

Comment: `@ManyToOne() @JoinColumn(name="teams")` are not on a field? At least it is not shown, please provide a complete [mre]

Comment: That was a copy and pasting mistake I've added in the lines now